# Optional Parameters with user input using C#

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, optional-parameters

So I am trying to get my console app on Visual Studio to accept a blank answer from the user, however, after two blank answers I get an error. I am utilizing a try/catch instead of an if/else, and it seems like my optional parameter is just not working the way I feel it should. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Program.cs code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Operator operatorObject = new Operator();
            Console.WriteLine("Pick a number:");
            int data = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Pick another number--optional");
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int result = operatorObject.operate(data, input);


            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch
        {
            Operator operatorObject = new Operator();
            int data = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
            int result = operatorObject.operate(data);
            Console.WriteLine(result);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

my class code:

```
public class Operator
{
    public int operate(int data, int input = 0)
    {
        return data + input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TryParse like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  try
  {
    Operator operatorObject = new Operator();
    Console.WriteLine("Pick a number:");
    int data = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Pick another number--optional");
    int input;
    bool inputResult = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);

    int result = operatorObject.operate(data, input);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
  catch
  {
    Operator operatorObject = new Operator();
    int data;
    bool dataResult = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out data);
    int result = operatorObject.operate(data);
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```